# Get value from DetailsView to FormView Textbox in insert mode

Tags: c#, asp.net, detailsview, formview

I'm trying to get the value from detailsview to formview. I want to set the Book ID/ISBN in formview insert textbox to Book ID/ISBN value from detailsview.

Here's a sample of my code:

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
            CellPadding="4" DataKeyNames="bookid" DataSourceID="detailsDataSource" 
            ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" Height="50px" Width="">
            <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <CommandRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" />
            <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
            <FieldHeaderStyle BackColor="#DEE8F5" Font-Bold="True" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <FooterTemplate>
                <asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
                    AllowSorting="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" 
                    DataKeyNames="reservationid" DataSourceID="reserveDataSource" 
                    ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None">
                    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" />
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmployeeID" HeaderText="Reserved by" 
                            SortExpression="EmployeeID" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="reservedate" HeaderText="Reserved date" 
                            SortExpression="reservedate" />
                    </Columns>
                    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
                    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
                    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
                    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
                </asp:GridView>
                <asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataKeyNames="reservationid" 
                    DataSourceID="reserveDataSource">
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        reservationid:
                        <asp:Label ID="reservationidLabel1" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Eval("reservationid") %>' />
                        <br />
                        bookid:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="bookidTextBox" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("bookid") %>' />
                        <br />
                        EmployeeID:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="EmployeeIDTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("EmployeeID") %>' />
                        <br />
                        reservedate:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="reservedateTextBox" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("reservedate") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                            CommandName="Update" Text="Update" />
                        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="UpdateCancelButton" runat="server" 
                            CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                    <InsertItemTemplate>
                        Book ID/ISBN:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="bookidTextBox" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Bind("bookid") %>'/>
                        <br />
                        Employee ID:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="EmployeeIDTextBox0" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("EmployeeID") %>' />
                        <br />
                        Reserve date:
                        <asp:TextBox ID="reservedateTextBox0" runat="server" 
                            Text='<%# Bind("reservedate") %>' />
                        <br />
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                            CommandName="Insert" Text="Reserve" />
                        &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" 
                            CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" />
                    </InsertItemTemplate>
```

So what I'm trying to do is when a user click the Insert/Reserve book linkbutton the Book ID/ISBN is already set to the Book ID/ISBN in formview insert mode as default.

Any help would be much appreciated ;)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try and check the `DetailsView1.SelectedValue`

```
<asp:TextBox ID="bookidTextBox" runat="server" 
                    Text='<%# DetailsView1.SelectedValue %>'/>
```

**Edit:**
Now if you want to bind that value to your Insert function of your `DetailsView`, it will not behave like the other control, since you are using the `Bind method` for the other control and it provides two way binding.

Now you need to pass that value to inserting evet of `DetailsView` like as we are assigning values using `DetailsView1.SelectedValue` but not binding the value.

I hope you understand this theory.

```
protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserting(object sender, DetailsViewInsertEventArgs e)
{
    e.Values["bookid"] = ((TextBox)DetailsView1.FindControl("bookidTextBox")).Text;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks it worked but it didnt bind to the record. How can I bind so that user can only type the reserve date?

Comment: Thanks! I'm still working on it, I'll try to see if I could get it right.