# ASP.NET Nested FormView

Tags: asp.net, data-binding, formview

I have this HTML.

```
<asp:FormView ID="FormView1" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
    <asp:FormView ID="FormView2" runat="server" DefaultMode="Insert" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource2">
       <asp:TextBox runat="Server" Text='<%# Eval("Terms") %>'></asp:TextBox>
    </asp:FormView>
</asp:FormView>
```

The code above works without any error but I want to get terms in the textbox fetched from SqlDataSource1 of FormView1 instead of FormView2 (SqlDataSource2). What I am missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the value of Parent formView DataSource value in child formview as what you are currently doing. But there is another way you set value. like..

```
protected void ChildFormWiew_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ChildFormView.CurrentMode == FormViewMode.Edit)
    {
        TextBox txtTemrs = ParentFormView.FindControl("Terms") as TextBox;
        ((TextBox)ChildFormView.FindControl("Terms")).Text = txtTemrs.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated question; try in this way.

Comment: Isn't really there a binding way?

Comment: FormView1 DataKeyName can be access, but other field I don't think so. like...Text='<%# DetailsView1.SelectedValue %>' and you can check this as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5879034/get-value-from-detailsview-to-formview-textbox-in-insert-mode/5879093#5879093