# Creating Entities outside DetailsView or FormView

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, data-binding, detailsview, formview

Using EntityFramework, I have created a page with a number of `DetailsView` and `FormView` controls to try and capture survey information (100% inserting; no updating or deleting) to be saved to sql server.  The tables/entities involved include Survey, Question, Respondent, Response, Answer and a couple of Type lookups.  (A Survey has a list of Questions and is completed by a Respondent.  The Respondent's Response has a list of Answers. An Answer answers a Question.)  Hopefully that all makes sense.

Rather than have the user click the autogenerated Insert button in each DetailsView or FormView, I would like to provide a single submit button to insert all the new data, which is what I am currently - and unsuccessfully - trying to code.  Essentially, i'm looking for a way to invoke the command called by autmatically created Insert button for each *Form.

I figured the way to do this is to loop through the DetailsView and FormView controls, saving (attaching?) the entities as I go along to the ObjectContext, and then calling SaveChanges() to get them all inserted into the db at once.  However, I'm having a problem accessing the new entities.  I don't seem to be able to access them through the FormView/DetailsView itself, and I can't seem to access the BoundFields within the *Views.

I tried to nest FormViews inside FormViews as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6001812/asp-net-nested-formview) infers it is possible, but I get the error `Type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.FormView' does not have a public property named 'FormView'.`

I'm about to start looking into solutions involving the `ObjectContext` and/or `EntityDataSource`s tied to the `DetailsView`s, but it seems to me that if I'm coming at it from that side, then I might as well use plain `TextBox`es and just loop through them creating all the entity stuff in code, rather than letting the databinding features kick in.

Can someone point to how I can run each *Form's insert button command to save all the newly created entities in each DetailsView/FormView or let me know if I should start looking in another area (eg ObjectContext or EntityDataSource)?

Many thanks
mcalex

Comment: Don't use data source and view controls for complex forms. They are not prepared for that. It is possible to bend them to work in such cases but it is complex and error prone. Just use a normal form with some javascript for adding new rows and for keeping information about removed rows and you will complete it much faster and you will have full control over the result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an idiot.

I just needed to call the *Form's `InsertItem` method.

Have no idea why I didn't realise the first time i read the API.